# Question related to the formal polynomial differentiation map

Tags: group-homomorphism

$D:\mathbb{F}[x]\to \mathbb{F}[x]$ is a group homomorphism of $(\mathbb{F}[x],+)$ into itself such that:
$$
D(a_0+a_1 x^1+......+a_n x^n)=a_1+2a_2 x^2+....\text{ etc}
$$

In the solution book it is said the image of $\mathbb{F}[x]$ by $D$ is $\mathbb{F}[x]$ with the proof that 
$$
D(1)=0
$$ 
and 
$$
D\left(\frac{1}{i+1}a_ix^{i+1}\right)=a_ix^i,
$$ 
but earlier in the text we only defined $n\cdot a$ for $a$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ and, given that, what is the meaning of $1/(i+1)\cdot a_i$? Is that it is some other element in $\mathbb{F}$ such that when multiplied by $I+1$ it should give out ai how can we be confident that such an element exists in $\mathbb{F}$?

Comment: For instance, in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ we could make sense of $1/3$ as $3^{-1}=2$.  In any ring with identity, an integer $n$ means $1 + 1 + \cdots + 1$ ($n$ times) when it is to be interpreted as a ring element. As long as this is invertible, that explains your fraction.

Comment: yea i'm aware that when our ring is commutative we can use the notation of division because it leads to no ambiguities but what i'm asking here is how is n.a is defined in our field F for a in F and n in Q rather than what we're usually accustomed to Z(the set of whole numbers)

Comment: $(p/q)a= p (\frac{1}{q}(a))$.

Comment: yea but what leads you to believe that 1/q(a) is indeed in F or that such an element even exists in the first place

Comment: The only issue is $\frac{1}{q}$.  This is in $F$ as long as $q \neq 0$ in $F$.  This is answered by the *characteristic* of the field $F$, which is either $0$ or a prime.  If you know that term, in characteristic $0$, $1/q$ will always make sense when $q\neq 0$.  In characteristic $p > 0$, $1/q$ will make sense as long as $q$ isn't a multiple of $p$.

Comment: welp that's pretty much the answer i was looking for thanx a lot for enlightening the way for me :o btw this is just some wild guess but could it be that you're from france?

Comment: Hopefully someone will write this up as an answer (I am on my phone).  And no, I am not from France.  I learned enough French to pass my PhD exam, but sadly, that's it ;)